# damaged file after using lseek function to change file position in c ( getting same size but corrupted content)

Tags: c, file, sockets, udp, lseek

I'm using lseek in my socket application to  to change the file position in case of packet drops and then  re-transmit dropped packets , so I'm changing the file position multiple times and I'm pretty sure that I'm setting position related parameters correctly. I'm getting the same file size at client side no problem with that , however the more that I change the file position the more i find myself unable to open the transmitted file.

do you have any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: So you are probably writing some garbage into your file. Give us more information, otherwise nobody can give you any useful hints.

Comment: Which program causes the corruption, the one on the client side or the one on the server side ?

Comment: In the server side i do the reading and positioning of the file , in the client side i write what i read in the server side. not sure where the problem is

Comment: Why are the struct packing pragmas commented out? Surely structure padding is one of the first suspects?

Comment: i have tested the struct by transmitting files without using lseek and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same compiler settings for both programs? Perhaps you have the data (byte) alignment that is not the same for each program.  Hence the size of your structs will differ, causing your seek calculations to be incorrect / different.

Comment: platform per se is not relevant - but I think I know what you mean, but if you use a different project - these can all have different byte alignments.   Have you checked?  What is the byte alignment?

Comment: I do think the byte alignment will give you what appears to be corrupt data... Easy to confirm if you check your settings.  One more thing is I'm not sure this pos = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_CUR); will give your desired result.  Use SEEK_SET or an offset other than zero